# Containment of Bruhat cells on flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, flag-varieties

This question was posted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764904/containment-of-bruhat-cells-on-flag-variety), but it did not receive any answer there.

Let $G$ be a connected semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb C$, $X$ the flag variety of $G$, $B_0$ a Borel subgroup, $\mathbb O$ a $B_0$-orbit on $X$.

**Question**: Can we always find a Borel subgroup $B_x$ so that the open $B_x$-orbit $\mathbb O'$ contains $\mathbb O$?

The obvious attempt would be to choose a point $\bar x \in \mathbb O$, and then take $B_x$ to be a Borel in opposite relative position to $B_{\bar x}$. But not all choices work. For example when $\mathbb O$ is the open orbit, choices are pretty restricted, and I'm failing to find a construction that works in general.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To make sure I understand: when $\mathbb O$ is open the only possible choice is $B_x=B_0$, correct? So it is "pretty restricted" but not very difficult to make =)

Comment: @imakhlin Yes, I think you are right. I meant to say that, if a procedure for choosing $B_x$ exists for any $B_0$-orbit $\mathbb O$, then it would receive more restrictions as $\mathbb O$ becomes bigger, and at the extreme case when $\mathbb O$ is the biggest possible orbit this procedure should give the unique solution $B_x = B_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the relevant fact here is as follows. For two Borels $B_1$ and $B_2$ with a common maximal torus $T$ let $x_1$ be the unique $T$-fixed point in the open $B_1$-orbit. Then the $B_2$-orbit $B_2x_1$ lies in the open $B_1$-orbit. For instance, you can see this by proving that
(a) for every $x\in B_2x_1$ the orbit closure $\overline{Tx}$ contains $x_1$ and
(b) the open $B_1$-orbit consists precisely of those points $x$ for which $x_1\in\overline{Tx}$.
(These are fairly basic properties of Schubert decompositions.)

In your setting this means that you can choose any maximal torus $T\subset B_0$, let $x'$ be the unique $T$-fixed point in $\mathbb O$ and consider the unique Borel $B\supset T$ for which the orbit $Bx'$ is open. This $B$ will be your $B_x$. In fact, this $B$ is the opposite (with respect to $T$) Borel of the stabilizer of $x'$. So in terms of your last paragraph you can choose any $\bar x$ but you have to choose the opposite Borel correctly: it must intersect $B_0$ in a maximal torus that fixes $\bar x$.